# Add spaces after punctuation marks with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I need to capitalize a txt file but I found some problems when I try to add a space after any punctuation mark with sed. For instance: "Hello,World" -> to "Hello, World"

I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# != 1 ]; then
  echo "No parameter"
  exit
fi

cp $1 $1.bak
ARCH1=/tmp/`basename $1`.$$

sed 's/[A-Z]*/\L&/g' $1 > $ARCH1 
sed -i 's/^./\u&/' $ARCH1

sed 's/  */\ /g' $ARCH1 #Here I replace >= 2 spaces for 1
sed 's/, */, /g' $ARCH1

#These 2 lines don't work well
sed 's/. */. /g' $ARCH1
sed 's/; */; /g' $ARCH1

mv $ARCH1 $1
```

The script doesn't crash, but the output is not the one that I expect.

Comment: Attach output please

Comment: *"The script doesn't crash, but the output is not the one that I expect..."* - Perhaps you should state what the actual problem is. *"... not the one that I expect"* is not a good problem statement.

Comment: you need to quote "$ARCH1" given the spaces, ';' in the path.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason your script doesn't work is that you forgot to pass `-i` to sed in several calls, and also that you don't escape `.` in the regex, so that `.` matches any character.

I also believe that a simpler way to do what you're trying to do is

```
sed -i.bak 's/[A-Z]*/\L&/g; s/\([.,;]\) */\1 /' "$1"
```

`-i.bak` edits the file in-place and creates a backup with the `.bak` extension, and the script is simply

```
s/[A-Z]*/\L&/g         # lower-case everything (I got that from your code)
s/\([.,;]\) */\1 /     # replace spaces after period, comma or semicolon
```

Here

- `[.,;]` is a character set matching period, comma or semicolon,
- `\(stuff\)` captures `stuff` in a group for later use, and
- `\1` is a back reference referring to the first such capture.

Note that this is a very simple approach. If your text, for example, contains ellipses (...), it'll waltz right over that and make `...` into `. . .`, and similar caveats apply for `?!` and such.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed:

```
$ echo "foo;BAR,BaZ.qux" | sed -r 's/[[:punct:]]+/& /g; s/[[:alnum:]]+/\L\u&/g'
Foo; Bar, Baz. Qux
```

`\L` lower cases the whole word, then `\u` upper cases the first character.

See your `regex(7)` man page for regular expression documentation.